# Run function After Completion of Previous function

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript. I got stuck in the middle of this code. I have searched a lot about this but I do not understand the answers.

This is my JavaScript Code :

I'm calling downloadImages3() function without executing the for loop next function is calling, but I want to execute downloadIamges4() after completion of downloadImages3().

```js
function downloadImages3() {
  var e = 0;
  var length = $(".myFile").length;
  alert("length=" + length);
  for (e = 0; e < $(".myFile").length; e++) {
    html2canvas($('myFile')[e], {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        imagenameurl.push(myImage);
        alert("myImage=" + myImage);
      }
    });

  } //for loop end
  downloadIamges4();
} // this is my first function and iam calling another function with "downloadIamges4()"

// this is another function

function downloadIamges4() {

  var url = "/xxxxxxx/download/ConvertVideo.action?sourceUrl=" + imagenameurl;
  alert("url=" + url);
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
      alert("response=" + response);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: There is a typo -> `$("myFile")`

Comment: @mplungjan can you explain with my code where i have to use that

Comment: @mplungjan i need to send that array through ajax call so thats why i used that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(".myFile").each(function() {
  html2canvas($(this), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      imagenameurl.push(myImage);
      if (imagenameurl.length == $(".myFile").length) downloadImages4();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for this answer this solved my question simpl answer without using any promises